# Android - GridView doesn't get centered in the screen

Tags: android, gridview

I came across this problem while making a launch pad activity. I have a `GridView` layout that is populated with app icons.  I want to center  it on the screen but just can not no matter what I've tried. If the icons are not enough to cover the whole screen width the GridView is aligned to the left. I put a white background in the `GridView` Layout to show the problem.

I change programmaticaly the size of the ImageView and the widthof the `GridView` column to offer more functionality so I see that increaasing the image size enough makes it look centered. But I want it to be centered regardless of the icons number or size. Can someone help?
(I also tried using a linear layout instead of a reletive for the `GridView`. no difference)

`GridView` Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Single grid-item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For **centering** in the middle of another layout (`RelativeLayout`), use

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

e.g. for a GridView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In order to make your Items fill the whole screen at all times, use `match_parent` for your item-width and use **weights**.